# error after installing new theme

Tags: admin, layout, adminhtml, theme, backend

I just installed a new theme and after clearing hte cache when i tried to login to the admin,it is showing blank page. Further debugging lead to the following:

> exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type:W3Themes_Themeoptions_Block_Adminhtml_Page_Menu' in /var/www/demo.xyz.com/app/Mage.php:563
>   Stack trace:        > #0 /var/www/demo.xyz.com/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Layout.php(469): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
>    #1 /var/www/demo.xyz.com/app/code/local/Aitoc/Aitsys/Model/Core/Layout.php(10): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->*getBlockInstance('adminhtml/page*...', Array)
>    #2 /var/www/demo.xyz.com/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Layout.php(411): Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Core_Layout->*getBlockInstance('adminhtml/page*...', Array)
>    #3 /var/www/demo.xyz.com/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Layout.php(446): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/page_...', 'menu')
>    #4 /var/www/demo.xyz.com/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Layout.php(238): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/page_...', 'menu')
>    #5 /var/www/demo.xyz.com/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Layout.php(204): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
>    #6 /var/www/demo.xyz.com/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
>    #7 /var/www/demo.xyz.com/includes     /src/Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action.php(345): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
>    #8 /var/www/demo.xyz.com/includes     /src/Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action.php(270):       Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
>    #9 /var/www/demo.xyz.com/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action.php(263): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
>    #10 /var/www/demo.xyz.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/ConfigController.php(91): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
>    #11 /var/www/demo.xyz.com/includes/src/Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action.php(420):    Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController->editAction()
>    #12 /var/www/demo.xyz.com/includes/src/Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
>    #13 /var/www/demo.xyz.com/includes/src/Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>    #14 /var/www/demo.xyz.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(347): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
>    #15 /var/www/demo.xyz.com/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>    #16 /var/www/demo.xyz.com/index.php(98): Mage::run('', 'store')
>    #17 {main}

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party module support.

Comment: @Marius : The theme provider is not providing support. So this is the only place where i can get some help.

Answer (score 1):

Problem:

> W3Themes_Themeoptions_Block_Adminhtml_Page_Menu

obviously this class doesn't exist.

Comment: :What should i do then?

Comment: Before this i had following problem :
Warning: include(W3Themes_Upsellslider_Model_Layout_Generate_Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/demo.xyz.com/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 93

So i disabled the xml file of this module. iS it correct aproach?

Comment: That warning means you are missing a file. It should be in your zipfile in `magma_package_1.4/magma_template_for_magento_1.8.zip/app/code/local/W3Themes/Upsellslider/Model/Layout/Generate/Observer.php`.
Once you added that file, re-enable the module.